# swift core data get objects from one to many relation

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have two entities and a simple one to many relation, Activity and CountedObject entities, and the relation Counted object can have multiple Activities
[image]

So in my code I was able to get the list of counted objects and now I want to calculate the sum of amount from activities related to specific counted object. Here is my code

```
let countedObject = countedObjects[indexPath.row]

let activities = countedObject.activities?.allObjects as! [Activity]
```

the problem is when I try to get activities I have an error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CountedObject activities]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000009d470'
```

Seems like the relation is not correct or something

Comment: have you added `Activity` object in `CountedObject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set relation correctly in CoreData just making relationship in table is not enough you have to set all relation object using an object ex.
 `countedObject.activity = activityObject`

Then after you can access `activityObjects` from `countedObject.activites`

Comment: Thanks a lot, saved my day, I created an extension of   CountedObject   and added this one self.activities = [Activity]() as? NSSet  to initializer